# Modify columns data type when importing from CSV to GeoPackage with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, csv, geopackage

I'm trying to import several CSV files into a GeoPackage using PyQGIS when opening a project as described in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364211/importing-csv-table-to-geopackage-with-pyqgis-using-csv-file-name/) using this code:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface
import glob
import os

def openProject():
    ruta = QgsProject.instance().absolutePath()
    tmp = ruta + '/tmp/'
    try:
        for csv in glob.glob(tmp + '*.csv'):
            rutacsv = 'file:///' + csv + '?delimiter=;'
            tabla = QgsVectorLayer(rutacsv, os.path.basename(csv), 'delimitedtext')

            opt= QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
            opt.EditionCapability = QgsVectorFileWriter.CanAddNewLayer
            opt.layerName = os.path.basename(csv).split('.csv', 1)[0]
            opt.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer
            QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(tabla, ruta + '/cdau.gpkg', opt)
```

Every CSV table has this structure:

```
id;date;code
1;2020-06-01 12:33:00;"00125"
2;2020-06-01 12:37:00;"00321"
...
```

But the column data types in the new tables in the GeoPackage are:

- id: Integer
- date: String
- code: Integer

I created this csvt file for every csv table but the result is the same:

```
"Integer(4)","DateTime(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)","String(5)"
```

I have searched for information about this, but found nothing about defining column data type when importing a table. Is there any way to define data types of columns when importing from CSV to GeoPackage using PyQGIS?

Comment: we need to see your code

Comment: Sorry, I just added my code.